# Give correct datatype to pytorch, but it does not accept

Tags: python, pytorch

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                input_size=12175,
                hidden_size=6,
                num_layers=1,
                batch_size=1,
                sequence_length=1,
                num_classes=6):
        """RNN and FC. hidden_size and num_classes MUST equal."""
        super().__init__()
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_size,
                         hidden_size=hidden_size,
                         batch_first=True)
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        
        # Fully-Connected layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(num_classes, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x, hidden):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        # Reshape input in (batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)
        x = x.view(self.batch_size, self.sequence_length, self.input_size)
        x = x.double()
        hidden = hidden.double()
        out, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)
        out = self.fc(out) # Add here
        return hidden, out
    
    def init_hidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)
```

And training

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

CLASS_LENGTH = 6

def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch, criterion):
    """
    This function has one line different from the ordinary `train()` function
    It has `make_variables()` to convert tuple of names to be a tensor
    """
    model.train()
    hidden = model.init_hidden()
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
#         hidden = hidden.view(model.batch_size, model.sequence_length, CLASS_LENGTH)
        output, hidden = model(data, hidden)

        tmp = output.view(model.batch_size, CLASS_LENGTH)
        loss = criterion(tmp, target)
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_idx % 1000 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))

def test(model, device, test_loader, criterion):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    y_test = []
    y_pred = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in tqdm(test_loader):
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output, hidden = model(data, hidden)
            tmp = output.view(-1, COUNTRY_LENGTH)
            test_loss += criterion(tmp, target).item() # sum up batch loss
            pred = tmp.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # get the index of the max log-probability

            pred_tmp = pred.view(-1)
            pred_list = pred_tmp.tolist()
            target_list = target.tolist()
            
            y_test += target_list
            y_pred += pred_list
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)

    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))
    
    # Confusion matrix
    confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    plot_confusion_matrix(confusion_mtx, classes=test_loader.dataset.countries, normalize=True,
                          title='Confusion matrix')
```

**Problem**:
I do not understand why it raise error since I am sure that I put correct datatype into it

```py
ipdb> n
> /tmp/ipykernel_16/2018411812.py(30)forward()
     29         hidden = hidden.double()
---> 30         out, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)
     31         out = self.fc(out) # Add here

ipdb> n
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float
> /tmp/ipykernel_16/2018411812.py(30)forward()
     29         hidden = hidden.double()
---> 30         out, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)
     31         out = self.fc(out) # Add here

ipdb> x
tensor([[[-5.6964e-01, -5.1070e-01, -5.9109e-01,  ...,  1.5597e-15,
           1.5597e-15,  1.5597e-15]]], dtype=torch.float64)
ipdb> hidden
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

pytorch version: `1.8.1+cu102`
OSX `10.15.7`
i7

**Question:**
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ensure type for `RNN`s input and hidden state, but it also contain some tensor parameters, weights, biases etc. To make them `double`, try `torch.set_default_tensor_type(t)` before `RNN` object construction, but I personaly would use `Float`.

```
...
super().__init__()
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.DoubleTensor)
self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_size,
                     hidden_size=hidden_size,
                     batch_first=True)
# may be turn defaults back to floats:
# torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov I did not set Double. I just follow the error msg. RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float. I did follow your answer. Same error persist.

Comment: I accept your answer. Since the error msg is changed to inplace problem

Comment: Error persisted if you changed default type back with `set_default_tensor_type(torch.FloatTensor)`, as `nn.Linear` requires parameter type changing as well. If you need to change defaults back, do it after `nn.Linear` construction.

Comment: It is version bingo. I downgrade to pytorch 1.4 and it woks. I will come back to it again later. Thank you for your attention